# How to automatically turn off an SCR after being latched for DC supply

Tags: switches, dc, scr

How to automatically turn off an SCR after being latched for DC supply?

Type of switches that turns on/off a circuit with a certain voltage

[image]

[image]

But when i try it in multisim it doesnt work.

Comment: Are you looking for a circuit or ideas in general? Please share some circuits you are trying presently.

Comment: you had to use forced commutation, the forward current must be forced to zero with an external circuit to commutate the SCR

Comment: A latch is used as a crowbar and is not a switch like a MOSFET

Comment: Can you justify why you want to use an SCR for this job in the first place. It seems to me that using a MOSFET to activate and deactivate the load is the most sensible approach. Forget about an SCR.

Comment: Separate the drive for the transistor  across the SCR from the SCR gate drive. When you pulse the transistor on it shorts the SCR which turns off. I do not know what advantage is sought doing this BUT it should work. You should name ALL components so we can refer to them by name and not in genmeral term as I have had to do above.

Comment: The transistor base is preventing the SCR from triggering. But you are driving the transistor and SCR with the same signal-- if you want to commutate the SCR you will need to do something like pulsing the transistor when you want the SCR to turn off.

Answer (score 2):

> Commutating circuit consist of components like inductors and capacitors called as commutating components. These commutating components cause to apply a reverse voltage across the SCR that immediately bring the current in the SCR to zero.
>
> Based on the manner in which the zero current achieved and arrangement of the commutating components, forced commutation is classified into different types such as class A, B, C, D, and E. This commutation is mainly used in chopper and inverter circuits.

This [article](http://www.electronicshub.org/scr-turn-off-methods/) explain various switch off method for SCR